# What is the bare minimum styling for a <a href=""> element

Tags: html, css, styles, href

After years of using the `<a>` tag I've never found an answer to a long-asked question.

To crack down on the stylings of a `<a>` tag I usually apply four styles:

```
.element:link{text-decoration:none;color:#CCC;}
.element:hover{text-decoration:none;color:#CCC;}
.element:active{text-decoration:none;color:#CCC;}
.element:visited{text-decoration:none;color:#CCC;}
```

Because as most of you probably know, browsers tend to apply a default underline and royal blue colour to links.

When I say **What is the bare minimum styling for a  element** is there a way I don't have to apply all of these styles? Will the `:hover`, `:active` and `:visited` inherit the `:link` style? and is it compatible across all browsers?

P.S.

I know that the above is the same as

```
.element:link, .element:hover, .element:active, .element:visited{text-decoration:none;color:#CCC;}
```

So please don't answer with that (:

Comment: Couldn't you just use .element {} and call it a day?

Comment: Be sure to read this section of the Selectors spec to understand how each of those selectors works: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#dynamic-pseudos

Comment: @Duniyadnd: Or `a.element` for that matter.

Comment: I have the feeling that it is best to be more verbose when using CSS, to account for strange behavior or old or obscure browsers.

Comment: @Duniyadnd - You should put that as an answer, not a comment because...that's the answer.

Comment: @BoltClock I have tried that but the browser seems to give it's own styling when you add a `href`

Comment: @F4r-20: Possibly a specificity issue then.

Comment: @F4r-20 - `a {color:green;}` works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5Tenn/ , unless you have another rule for all links in your page (as BoltClock suggested).

Comment: What isn't clear to me, is what you mean by "bare minimum styling". Do you mean the minimum amount of code needed to *remove* the default styles that browsers add to the `<a>` element?

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry about that reading the question over now, it seems a bit silly. I should have said *"for a custom element"* or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bare minimum is **no styling at all** -- so that the browser will automatically apply its default styles.

The usual default is indeed royal blue for link, red or purple for visited, and nothing in particular for the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Answered because @Rob said I should put it here

```
a.element{}
```

or

```
.element {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use

```
.element {text-decoration:none;color:#CCC;}
```

and that's it.
If you want to additionally style `:hover` or `:active` state, you do it after `.element {}`
If you want it to apply to all your links, you can use

```
a {text-decoration:none;color:#CCC;}
```